# subset data based on matrix of values in R

Tags: r, subset

say I have the following data and I wish to subset according to

```
set.seed(123)
a <- rep(1:21)
b <- rep(1:7)
c <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
d <- sample(1:4, 21, replace = TRUE)

e <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
e

X <- subset(e, (c==1 & d>2))
X$b

f <- subset(e, b != X$b)
```

So in other words, `X$b` shows the b values I want to remove from `e`

Comment: You probably looking for `subset(e, !b %in% X$b)`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327971/subtracting-one-data-frame-from-the-other